# Undefined control sequence \eq

Tags: math-mode, errors

I am just starting using LaTeX and there's a problem I cannot solve.
See, I want to make a plan so I use this code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,landscape]{slides}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\title{Dynamique des fonctions et le probl$\grave{e}$me du chaos}

\textit{Probl$\acute{e}$matique : }
 Pouvons-nous trouver une mani$\grave{e}$re de corriger la composante chaotique d'un syst$\grave{e}$me ?

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \emph{Introduction au chaos : la famille des fonctions quadratiques : $Q_{\mu}(x)\eq \mu.x.(1-x)$}

    \begin{itemize}%[label = \Alph*]
        \item[A] D$\acute{e}$but d'analyse : points fixes attracteurs
        \item[B] Apparition du chaos, d$\acute{e}$finitions
    \end{itemize}

    \item \emph{Une tentative de correction du chaos : $\acute{e}$tude de la fonction $f_{\mu,\lambda}\eq \mu.x.(1-x) + \lambda.x.(1+x)$}

    \begin{itemize}%[label = \Alph]
        \item[A] Mise en place de simplification et $\acute{e}$tude du point fixe choisi
        \item[B] Etude graphique de quelques r$\acute{e}$sultats
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

\input{transparent_plan}
```

And for my emphasized titles, I have these messages of error :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.23 ...es fonctions quadratiques : $Q_{\mu}(x) \eq
                                                    \mu.x.(1-x)$
```

and the other message is :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...e la fonction $f_{\mu,\lambda} \eq
                                                 \mu.x.(1-x) + \lambda.x.(1+x)
l.30 ...lambda} \eq \mu.x.(1-x) + \lambda.x.(1+x)
```

Please, can somebody help me to understand this situation ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When you look at an error message like that, the macro (control sequence) that is undefined is that last one before the line break, in this case `\eq`. What should it represent?

Comment: why are you using math mode for e-acute?

Comment: In other words, `\eq` is not defined so `latex` don't know what to do with this macro. It seems you might have copy-paste your code and forgot to also copy-past the definition of `\eq` (`\newcommand{\eq}{...}`) or load the relevant package. (By the way, using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead of `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` will enable you to directly type `é` instead of  `$\acute{e}$` or `\'{e}!)

Comment: Welcome, for a start a more modern class than `slides` might be a good idea? You can try out `beamer`.

Comment: Typing `=` is shorter than `\eq` ;-) If you want to have an equal sign, of course.

Comment: @ebo `é` and similar accented characters are also supported by `latin1`

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't thought that "\eq" was not something used in LaTex :)

Comment: To Johannes_B : Thanks for the advice, but I have to print this document on slide, will it work ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on previous comments, here is a 'debugged' version of your code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,landscape]{slides}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

        \title{Dynamique des fonctions et le problème du chaos}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \textit{Problématique : }
     Pouvons-nous trouver une manière de corriger la composante chaotique d'un système ?

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \emph{Introduction au chaos : la famille des fonctions quadratiques : $Q_{\mu}(x) = \mu.x.(1-x)$}
        \begin{itemize}%[label = \Alph*]
            \item[A] Début d'analyse : points fixes attracteurs
            \item[B] Apparition du chaos, définitions
        \end{itemize}

        \item \emph{Une tentative de correction du chaos : étude de la fonction $f_{\mu,\lambda} = \mu.x.(1-x) + \lambda.x.(1+x)$}
        \begin{itemize}%[label = \Alph]
            \item[A] Mise en place de simplification et étude du point fixe choisi
            \item[B] Etude graphique de quelques résultats
        \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Modifications:

- replace `$\acute{e}$` by `é` and `$\grave{e}$` by `è`
- include `\maketitle`
- replace `\eq` by `=`
- delete `\input{transparent_plan}` : since it appears after `\end{document}`, it won't be interpreted and is thus useless.

---

However, as pointed out by `Johannes_B`, the `beamer` class might me more indicated in your case. You can define your slides as following, and automatically generate a handout.

Here is thus an 'improved' version of your original code, using `beamer`. (Note that I don't use fames, nor layer, what would make the presentation more dynamic)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{beamer}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{geometry}
        \geometry{hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
    \usepackage{calc}
    %\usepackage{enumitem}

        \title{Dynamique des fonctions et le problème du chaos}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame} 
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Un titre}

        \emph{Problématique : } % \emph is better than \textit since it describes "what" you want to do, and not "how" (for "how, trust LaTeX !)
         Pouvons-nous trouver une manière de corriger la composante chaotique d'un système ?
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \emph{Introduction au chaos : la famille des fonctions quadratiques : $Q_{\mu}(x) = \mu.x.(1-x)$}
            \begin{enumerate}[A.]
                \item Début d'analyse : points fixes attracteurs
                \item Apparition du chaos, définitions
            \end{enumerate}

            \item \emph{Une tentative de correction du chaos : étude de la fonction $f_{\mu,\lambda} = \mu.x.(1-x) + \lambda.x.(1+x)$}
            \begin{enumerate}[A.]
                \item Mise en place de simplification et étude du point fixe choisi
                \item Etude graphique de quelques résultats
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

To generate a handout, just replace the first line by:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
```

Comment: I'd remove `geometry` from the `beamer` version. Edit: and if one wants an aspectratio closer to that of A4, `aspectratio=32` in the class options.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly type accented letters in your code, with the `utf8` input encoded (even accented capital letters – cf `Etude` vs `Étude`). This encoding is known to all modern systems. Also, I replaced `\eq` with `=`, `.` with `\cdot` for multiplication dots, and the clumsy `itemize` environments with `\item[A]` &c.  with a simple nested `enumerate`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,landscape, french]{slides}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
%
\title{Dynamique des fonctions et le problème du chaos}

\textit{Problématique : }
 Pouvons-nous trouver une manière de corriger la composante chaotique d'un système ?

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \emph{Introduction au chaos : la famille des fonctions quadratiques : $Q_{\mu}(x) = \mu\cdot x\cdot (1-x)$}

 \begin{enumerate}[label = \Alph*]
 \item Début d'analyse : points fixes attracteurs
 \item Apparition du chaos, définitions
 \end{enumerate}

 \item \emph{Une tentative de correction du chaos : étude de la fonction $f_{\mu,\lambda} = \mu\cdot x\cdot (1-x) + \lambda\cdot x\cdot (1+x)$}

 \begin{enumerate}[label = \Alph*]
 \item Mise en place de simplification et étude du point fixe choisi
 \item Étude graphique de quelques résultats
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]